# Callee specifying more spectific behaviour of the caller

Tags: c#, unity3d

I am working on a game in Unity/C#. I have a section of code that both feels like the best solution and code smell.

There are two objects. A player, and something interactable. The interactable object defines a method from an interface `IInteractable` with the signature `void Interact(GameObject interactor)`. The player can call this method on any `IInteractable` object.

The player object implements an `IHolder` interface, and the object in question that implements `IInteractable` is of type `Holdable`.

When the player calls `Interact()` on the `Holdable`, the `Holdable` checks if the caller implements `IHolder` by using a generic method call. If it succeeds then it makes the holder call a more specific method on it's own instance.

```
public void Interact(GameObject interactor)
{
    if (interactor.TryGetComponent<IHolder>(out this.holder))
    {
        this.holder.Hold(this);
    }
}
```

It doesn't feel right to me that the object to be held is commanding the holder to hold it.

Would a more appropriate solution be to have `Interact()` return an `Action<GameObject>` that the player can decide to `.Invoke()`? Not sure if having the caller call the callee's suggestion to call the caller's method with the callee as an argument is actually better and not just hiding the issue with complexity.

Edit:

Using this refactor as the solution:

```
public Action GetInteraction(GameObject interactor)
{
    IHolder potentialHolder;
    if (interactor.TryGetComponent<IHolder>(out potentialHolder))
    {
        return () => potentialHolder.Hold(this);
    }

    return null;
}
```